# Refer to object elements name instead of content

Tags: jquery, regex, arrays, object, match

Below is an object that contains of regular expressions that are used in the function below to look for match in some strings that are to be found in an array.

If it's a match I want is to check if the match is a car accident (i.e a match in the last element in the object) or not.

On line 27 I try to do that, but that doesn't work because INCIDENT_MATCHES[type] refers to the object element's content (i.e the regular expression), not the name of the element (trafficAccidents).

What do I write to refer to the elements name instead of it's content?

```
 1. var INCIDENT_MATCHES = {
 2.     battery: /\w*(bråk)\w*|överfall|slagsmål|slogs|misshandel|misshandlad|\w*(tjuv)\w*/ig,
 3.     burglaries: /snattade|snattare|snatta|inbrott|bestulen|stöld|\w*(tjuv)\w*/ig,
 4.     robberies: /\w*(rån)\w*|personrån|\w*(ryckning)\w*|väskryckt*/ig,
 5.     gunfire: /skottlossning|skjuten|sköt/ig,
 6.     drugs: /narkotikabrott/ig,
 7.     vandalism: /skadegörelse|klotter|\w*(klottra)\w*/ig,
 8.     trafficAccidents: /(trafik|bil)olycka|(trafik|bil)olyckor|\w*(personbil)\w*|singelolycka|kollision|\w*(kollidera)\w*|påkörd|trafik|smitningsolycka/ig,
 9. };
10.
11. function FindIncidents(incidentReports) {
12.
13.     var incidentCounts = {};
14.     var incidentTypes = Object.keys(INCIDENT_MATCHES);
15.     incidentReports[2].forEach(function(incident) {
16.         matchFound = false;
17.
18.         incidentTypes.forEach(function(type) {
19.             if(typeof incidentCounts[type] === 'undefined') {
20.                 incidentCounts[type] = 0;
21.             }
22.             var matchFound = incident.match(INCIDENT_MATCHES[type]);
23.             if(matchFound){
24.                 matchFound = true;
25.                 incidentCounts[type] += 1;
26.                 console.log(INCIDENT_MATCHES[type]); // refers to the elements content, not the name which I want.
27.                 if (INCIDENT_MATCHES[type] == 'trafficAccidents') {
28.                     //
29.                 }
30              }
31.         });
32.     });
33.  }
34.
35.    FindIncidents(arrayWithStringsToMatch);
```

Comment: Why do you use `Object.keys().forEach()`??? Why not a simple for-in-loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do I write to refer to the elements name instead of it's content?

It's just `type`.

Comment: Oh, that easy! Thanks a lot :-)